# LDAP search on multiple fields like an if/else-statement

Tags: filter, attributes, ldap

I have a question regarding LDAP search, i have three attributes that i want to involve in my filter.
I want that the filter always shall search for objectClass, if attribute skaPersonType has a value, look for that, else look for employeeType.
I'm stuck and really don't now how to continue.

Best regards / C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Always search for objectclass

Unnecessary, but `(objectClass=*)`: all LDAP entries have an `objectClass.`

> 2. IF skaPerson=EMP is met, look for that value

`(skaPerson=EMP)`

> 3. ELSE look for employeetype=External

`(employeetype=External)`

> Any ideas how i can manage that?

You're looking for (2) *or* (3). So:

```
(|(skaPerson=EMP)(employeetype=External))
```

If you must have the redundant `objectClass` test:

```
(&(objectClass=*)(|(skaPerson=EMP)(employeetype=External)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Solved it the same way as you last night. Great support here.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what filter you actually want:

> ...always shall search for objectClass, if attribute skaPersonType has a
>   value, look for that, else look for employeeType...

Are you looking for something like this?

```
(&(objectClass=MyClass)(|(skaPersonType=A)(&(!(skaPersonType=*))(employeeType=B))))
```

Above filter will get object which:

1. objectClass equals MyClass, AND
2. one of following condition is met

   - skaPersonType equals A, OR
   - skaPersonType has no value, and employeeType equals B

**The code is not tested.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm even not sure if it's possible to solve it the way i'm trying. What i'm trying to to is that:
1. Always search for objectclass
2. IF skaPerson=EMP is met, look for that value
3. ELSE look for employeetype=External

Any ideas how i can manage that? 
Grateful for any kind of help!

Comment: Seems @EJP provide the filter according to your criteria already. Is that what you want?